# How to set different fonts for headings, text and captions

Tags: fonts, titlesec

I want my

1. Chapter names, section/subsection/... and other similar titles to be in `gfsneohellenic`
2. Main text to be in `libertine` and `libertinust1math`.
3. The captions of figures and tables will be some sans serif font as well, which I have not decided yet.

Using either

```
%\usepackage[default]{gfsneohellenic}
%\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
```

OR

```
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

sets the whole document to be in the respective fonts.

I am not being able to set the fonts specifically in `titlesec`, i.e. I am not being able to understand how to pass the specific fonts as parameters in the following -

```
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\medium}
```

PS - I am using Overleaf.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... `Overleft` have its own `supporting team`, if possible please approach them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `default` option with `gfsneohellenic` it sets both `\rmdefault` and `\sfdefault` to `gfsneohellenic`. If you leave out that option, you have finer control:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR, T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage{gfsneohellenic}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{neohellenic}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\normalsize\sffamily}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The particular fontname `neohellenic` is learned from `gfsneohellenic.sty`. 
Result:

[image]

Note that I have changed your definition for `\subsubsection`, since there is no `\medium` command in LaTeX.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you, this worked. :D